# how to prevent resubmitting after click f5

Tags: php, forms

how to prevent resubmitting after click f5

i want after uploaded prevent f5 php

i try `header();` and `include '';`

but not working!

any solution?

my form

```
<form id="pic-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="pic.php" method="POST">
<input name="uploadedfile" id="pic-upload" type="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="upload" id="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

my php code

```
<? include 'var.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
if($terms == 'yes'){
if ((($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < $max_file_size)
&& in_array($extension, $formats))
{   
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], 
$uploaded );
echo '<img src="'.$url.$uploaded.'"/>';
echo '<h3>'.$url.$short.'</h3>';
}
elseif(!empty ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"])){
echo '<h3>Please choose file to upload it!</h3>'; // if you don't choose file
}
elseif(!in_array($extension, $formats)){
echo '<h3>This extension is not allowed!</h3>'; // if you choose file not allowed
}
elseif($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] = $max_file_size ){
echo "Big size!"; // if you choose big file
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you considered indenting or formatting your code?

Comment: Basically, prevent a user from submitting the form twice?

Comment: google search "post get redirect". you can use header to refresh the page and pass an id or some reference to the action. Remember, header location will only work if you have not output anything to the browser

Answer (score 0):

No way to prevent this directly. You can have the PHP form handler use `header()` to redirect the page to a results page that has no data posted to it. If the user refeshes that page (F5), then there is no re-post.

This also means you will have to validate the form before it's submitted or pass the results along via URL. Example:

```
<? include 'var.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  if($terms == 'yes'){
    if ((($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < $max_file_size)
    && in_array($extension, $formats)){   
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploaded );
      $src = $url.$uploaded;
      $short = $url.$short;
    }
    elseif(!empty ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"])){
      $error = '<h3>Please choose file to upload it!</h3>'; // if you don't choose file
    }
    elseif(!in_array($extension, $formats)){
      $error = '<h3>This extension is not allowed!</h3>'; // if you choose file not allowed
    }
    elseif($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] = $max_file_size ){
      $error = "Big size!"; // if you choose big file
    }
  }
}
if(isset($error)){
  header("location: errorpage.php?e=$error");
}else {
  header("location: successpage.php?sr=$src&sh=$short");
}
?>
```

Comment: the fact that they're sending the post to another page doesn't negate the need to validate the front end or back end.  You should ALWAYS validate inputs on client side AND server side.

Comment: Agreed @Snowburnt. I did not want to create a new issue by echoing before the header is handled.

Comment: mr Twisty, i want include 'succes.php';

Comment: Including a page would then defeat the whole reason to do it this way. It is a feature of the browser to attempt to re-post the data upon a refresh. This only happens when you refresh a page that has had data posted to it directly. What I am suggesting is that you handle the form in one PHP page and then essentially perform a redirect to a page without posting data to it. When the user hits refresh, they will not be prompted to re-post the data since it's already been handled. I hope that makes sense.